# Interfacing ROS2 bag files with DPDK

Tags: ros2, dds, rosbag2

Has there been any work on interfacing ROS2 and [DPDK, Data Plane Development Kit](https://www.dpdk.org/)? Given that multiple HD cameras inputting over Ethernet may flood an NIC, DPDK could help out as a middleware implementation, but my Google searches have turned up absolutely nothing. Is anyone aware of literature regarding this issue?